# Dojo Load Content into Existing View and Perform Transition creates new views outside page

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, dojox.mobile

I tried to make a function to load external view htmlpages into a view and then perform a transition. But when my function loads it opens 2 views outside my page with only a header with the title "my application" and a backbutton with "home" as title. I get no errors, but I doesn't do what it has to do.

This is my function.

```
    goTo : function(viewId){
        WL.Logger.debug("goTo function START");


        var home= "mainView";
        require(["dojo/dom",  "dijit/registry" , "dojo/on", "dojox/mobile/View","dojo/domReady!"], 
                function(dom, registry, on, view){

        var currentView = registry.byId(home).getShowingView();
        var view = registry.byId(viewId);

        WL.Logger.debug("viewId =" + viewId + ", currentViewId=" + currentView.id);

        if(currentView.id != viewId){
            var url = "views/klappr/"+viewId+".html";
            // view.destroyDescendants();

            dojo.xhrGet({
                url: url,
                handleAs: "text",
                load: function(response, ioArgs){
                    view.innerHTML = response;
                    //parser.parse(view);
                    currentView.performTransition(viewId, 1, "slide"); 
                }
            });


            //dijit.registry.byId(viewId).transitionTo({ url: url, transition: "slide", transitionDir: 1, urlTarget:viewId });
        }
        });
    }
```

These are the view that are created. (That don't have to be created)

```
    <div class="mblView" id="dojox_mobile_IconContainer_0_mblApplView"         widgetid="dojox_mobile_IconContainer_0_mblApplView" style="visibility: visible;"><h1 class="mblHeading mblHeadingCenterTitle" id="dojox_mobile_Heading_1" widgetid="dojox_mobile_Heading_1" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><span role="button" class="mblToolBarButton mblToolBarButtonHasLeftArrow" tabindex="0" id="dojox_mobile_ToolBarButton_0" dir="ltr" widgetid="dojox_mobile_ToolBarButton_0"><span class="mblToolBarButtonArrow mblToolBarButtonLeftArrow mblColorDefault mblColorDefault45"></span><span class="mblToolBarButtonBody mblColorDefault"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="mblToolBarButtonText"><tbody><tr><td class="mblToolBarButtonIcon"></td><td class="mblToolBarButtonLabel">Home</td></tr></tbody></table></span></span><span class="mblHeadingSpanTitle" style="">My Application</span><div class="mblHeadingDivTitle" role="heading" aria-level="1">My Application</div></h1><div class="mblContainer" id="dojox_mobile_Container_0" widgetid="dojox_mobile_Container_0"><div class="mblIconItemPane" id="dojox_mobile__IconItemPane_0" widgetid="dojox_mobile__IconItemPane_0" style="display: none;"><h2 class="mblIconItemPaneHeading"><div class="mblIconItemPaneIcon" role="" title="" tabindex="0"><div title="" class="mblDomButtonBlueMinus mblDomButton"><div><div></div></div></div></div><span class="mblIconItemPaneTitle">Klas 1A</span></h2><div class="mblContent"></div></div><div class="mblIconItemPane" id="dojox_mobile__IconItemPane_1" widgetid="dojox_mobile__IconItemPane_1" style="display: none;"><h2 class="mblIconItemPaneHeading"><div class="mblIconItemPaneIcon" role="" title="" tabindex="0"><div title="" class="mblDomButtonBlueMinus mblDomButton"><div><div></div></div></div></div><span class="mblIconItemPaneTitle"></span></h2><div class="mblContent"></div></div></div></div>
    <div class="mblView" id="dojox_mobile_IconContainer_1_mblApplView" widgetid="dojox_mobile_IconContainer_1_mblApplView" style="visibility: visible; display: none;"><h1 class="mblHeading mblHeadingCenterTitle" id="dojox_mobile_Heading_2" widgetid="dojox_mobile_Heading_2" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><span role="button" class="mblToolBarButton mblToolBarButtonHasLeftArrow" tabindex="0" id="dojox_mobile_ToolBarButton_1" dir="ltr" widgetid="dojox_mobile_ToolBarButton_1"><span class="mblToolBarButtonArrow mblToolBarButtonLeftArrow mblColorDefault mblColorDefault45"></span><span class="mblToolBarButtonBody mblColorDefault"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="mblToolBarButtonText"><tbody><tr><td class="mblToolBarButtonIcon"></td><td class="mblToolBarButtonLabel">Home</td></tr></tbody></table></span></span><span class="mblHeadingSpanTitle" style="">My Application</span><div class="mblHeadingDivTitle" role="heading" aria-level="1">My Application</div></h1><div class="mblContainer" id="dojox_mobile_Container_1" widgetid="dojox_mobile_Container_1"><div class="mblIconItemPane" id="dojox_mobile__IconItemPane_2" widgetid="dojox_mobile__IconItemPane_2" style="display: none;"><h2 class="mblIconItemPaneHeading"><div class="mblIconItemPaneIcon" role="" title="" tabindex="0"><div title="" class="mblDomButtonBlueMinus mblDomButton"><div><div></div></div></div></div><span class="mblIconItemPaneTitle">Klas 1A</span></h2><div class="mblContent"></div></div><div class="mblIconItemPane" id="dojox_mobile__IconItemPane_3" widgetid="dojox_mobile__IconItemPane_3" style="display: none;"><h2 class="mblIconItemPaneHeading"><div class="mblIconItemPaneIcon" role="" title="" tabindex="0"><div title="" class="mblDomButtonBlueMinus mblDomButton"><div><div></div></div></div></div><span class="mblIconItemPaneTitle"></span></h2><div class="mblContent"></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: ps. I based my code on this http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/dynamic-content-loading.html

Comment: I found out that the load function of dojo.xhrGet never is called. Maybe that is why the other views are created.

I think it can't read the local url to my html page.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

- Using the relevant parts of your code (which doesn't run as-is), I tested it successfully with both Dojo 1.9.0 and 1.8.3, that is the load() function gets called as expected.
- Did you check the console in case it shows exceptions? Did you check that the execution flow arrives till the call of dojo.xhrGet? (if you can't breakpoint, use an alert() call). Did you check that the "url" variable points to a file which actually exists?
- Just in case, did you require the dojo/_base/xhr module, which is mandatory such that dojo.xhrGet is defined?
- You did not mention your Worklight nor Dojo version (which are always useful information). Can you tell the content of dojo.version?
- Starting with Dojo 1.8, dojox.xhrGet is deprecated, in favor of
  dojo/request/xhr (see
  https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/xhrGet.html). The Dojo Mobile doc that you pointed is indeed missing an update; this doc will be fixed. However, as said above, the deprecated API does work in my testing, I just mention it for your information.
- Finally, a suggestion: if you are using WL 6.0+ (thus, Dojo 1.9+), you might consider using dojox.app (see tutorials at https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/dojox_app/ ).